# Mother Board 2666MHz with DDR4 266MHz RAM and a 2933MHz processor

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard

Mother Board 2666MHz with DDR4 266MHz RAM and a 2933MHz processor will it work.
Because the RAM and motherboard are slower than the Proc

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no link between RAM and CPU frequency. The frequency of the RAM will only affect how many times the CPU will be able to read/write on it, but it will not limit the CPU itself since it use it's cache most of the time.

This situation is pretty common so there is no reason to worry here.